# Where is the location to login to access to infura links

Tags: infura

In https://infura.io/ I see the "Get Started" button that leads me to the sign up page, like this, https://infura.io/signup.

The problem is I already signed up before. How do I sign in now?

Last time I signed up to use the ropsten link. Now I want to use the mainnet link. Apparantly I did not write it down last time. I do not want to use a different email address every time to see the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no sign-in.

When you signed up they will have emailed you your personal provider URLs, which contain your own access token. The email will have been entitled "Welcome to INFURA!".

Example URL: `https://mainnet.infura.io/<your_access_token>`

The email also contains your personal Ropsten URL, together with an IPFS gateway and IPFS RPC endpoint.